# Annotated class not found in jar file generated by maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, annotations, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using the maven-assembly-plugin to generate a jar file with a single class inside. When I try to deploy my jar to JBoss server I receive an error: No annotated classes found in the jar:. I've decompiled the class file from the jar and it is annotated. My only guess is for some reason the maven-assembly-plugin is causing an issue. If I generate the jar from a command line and inserting the same .class file the deployment will work.

snippet of the plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-RC04InquirySvc-v1.jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>true</runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>RC04InquirySvc-v1</finalName>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly-RC04InquirySvc-v1.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Vendor>EDS</Implementation-Vendor>
                        <Implementation-Title>Agile Card Framework</Implementation-Title>
                        <Implementation-Version>6.0</Implementation-Version>
                        <Built-Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Built-Date>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And the assembly file:

```xml
<assembly>
    <id>acf-bundle</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes/com/eds/agilecard/wsdl/rc04Inquirysvc_v1</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/com/eds/agilecard/wsdl/rc04Inquirysvc_v1</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/ServiceEndpointImpl.class</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Did you unarchived the jars ? What are the differences between the jar generated by maven and the jar generated by the command line ? What files are more or lacking and in which jar ?

Comment: They look exactly the same. I ended up using an ANT task to generate the jar and it fixed the issue. So, still not sure why the assembly approach didn't work

Comment: And does also the two manifests contain exactly the same information ?